# Underfull \hbox (badness 1043) in paragraph at lines 52--52

Tags: errors, badness

I have this bad error with Latex, and i can't resolve it can somebody help me ? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/coco/Desktop/School/TM/Ts_temps.pdf}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14 cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21 cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5 pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\large}
{\thesection.}{0.3em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0.2em}{0.2em}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries \itshape \normalsize}
{\thesubsection.}{0.3em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0.2em}{0.2em}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\bfseries\normalsize\itshape}
{\thesubsubsection.}{0.3em}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.1em}{0.1em}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead[L]{Corentin Rouault}
\fancyhead[R]{TM Beaulieu}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{CALCULS AUTOUR DU DIOXYDE DE CARBON}
\end{center}

\section*{Quantité en $kg$ de $CO_2$ dans l'atmosphère à partir d'une concentration en ppm}

Pour trouver la masse totale de $CO_2$ présente dans l'atmosphère grâce à une concentration en ppm, il nous faut connaitre le nombre total de moles de $CO_2$ dans l'atmosphère, grâce à une formule chimique de base :
\begin{equation}
n = \dfrac{m}{M} \Rightarrow n_{atmosphère} = \dfrac{m_atmosphère}{M_airsec}
\end{equation}
Où $n$ est le nombre de moles, $m$ est la masse (g) et $M$ est la masse molaire.\\
Étant donné que la grande partie du ${CO_2}$ présent dans l'atmosphère se situe dans la 
troposphère\footnote{fr.wikipedia.org. "Troposphère". (24 août 2021)}\footnote{La troposhère est la couche la plus basse de l'atmosphère} nous pouvons adopter comme masse celle de la troposphère. Cette dernière est approximativement égal aux 3/4 de la masse de l'atmosphère globale\footnote{u-picardie.fr, BEAUCHAMP Jacques. "L'ATMOSPHÈRE". (28 novembre 2005, consulté le 13 septembre 2021)} qui elle même est égale à $\sim 5.29\cdot 10^18 kg$\quad \footnotemark[3].
```

Comment: it's not an error just a warning that tex has had to stretch inter-word space in that paragraph,

Comment: Yes normally like i saw in other errors like that by i can't success to compose my code

Comment: Off topic:  You might check the shape of the typeset quotes around "Troposphere" and elsewhere.  They might well all be "closing quotes", which isn't good form typographically.  If they are, you can get opening quotes on the left by typing two of the "grave accents" (I'm not sure where that might be on the keyboard you are probably using) or take a look at the `csquotes` package, which was created to handle situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE which compiled after I added `\end{document}` at the end.

The `underfull \hbox...` Is just an indication (warning?) that the interword spacing has been adjusted to make the line fit better.

There were also two

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \` invalid in math mode on input line 50.
```

I suggest you ignore the `\hbox` until you have resolved the `invalid in math mode` problem which I guess gives you unexpected typesetting.

Comment: Thank you, it was just a stupid error